# Lazy loading modules with angularjs and requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have been tackling this issue for a long time with great difficulty since there are a lot of articles that show how to load directives, services, and other angular components that use the word module to describe them.. ending up with an SEO nightmare.

All the solutions are incredibily complex, making dividing the JS files almost not relevant.

Has someone found a simple way to inject an angular module dependency to the main module when it's needed ?

Note: since I'm using require.js the actual JS is already present (also lazyloaded just when it's needed). So all that really is needed is to inject the modules onto angular.

Here is how close I got:

1. window function in index.html to load the secondary .js file

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var hasBackLoaded = false;
   function loadBackOfficeJs (cb) {
       console.log("loadBackOfficeJs");
       if(!hasBackLoaded){
           var newScript = document.createElement('script');
           newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
           newScript.src = '<%=dist_cdn%>/scripts/back.js';
           newScript.onload = backLoaded;
           document.body.appendChild(newScript);
           function backLoaded(){
               console.log("back loaded")
               hasBackLoaded = true;
               cb();
           }

       } else {
           cb();
       }
   }
   ```
2. call the previous function and try to load the angular modules into angular

   `loadBackOfficeJs(function(){
       require(['back'], function(){
           //angular modules should be injected here.. somehow
       });
   });`

Comment: Good [article by senior paypal engineer](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/sane-scalable-angular-apps-are-tricky-but-not-impossible-lessons-learned-from-paypal-checkout-c5320558d4ef#.mhtf6rdzx) that says "don't bother lazy loading angular"

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this lib [ocLazyload](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

Most basic usecase is to load a module thanks to the provided $ocLazyLoad service.

```
$ocLazyLoad.load('yourModule.js');
```

This [article](http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/) was written by the lib's author when he started the library. Though it's a bit old now it's a good entry point to the internals of lazy loading modules.

Comment: I'm looking for a more direct approach since this library is quite heavy and complex